# Bounding rect of multiline string in UILabel swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have been trying for hours now to find the `boundingRect` of a string in a UILabel I have, but nothing seems to be working.

From what I understand, `boundingRect` returns the size of the actual text in the label, not the label's size or something like that. This is true, right?

I have a `UILabel` called `messageLabel` which contains some text that wraps to an unlimited number of lines.

The code I have now is this:

```
let labelRect = (message as NSString).boundingRect(with: messageLabel.frame.size, 
    options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, 
    attributes: [NSFontAttributeName : messageLabel.font], 
    context: nil)
```

Unfortunately, this returns totally wrong dimensions for my text.

What is the correct way to return the dimensions of text in a multiline UILabel?

Comment: Are you trying to calculate the size needs for a string that is already set in the label and the label is already sized to fit the string, or are you trying to calculate the height needed for a string based on a font and a desired width?

Comment: You should update your question with key information such as the value of `messageLabel.frame.size` and `labelRect`.

Comment: @rmaddy, I don't think `labelRect` has a set value. In the question, the OP is assigning the value to `labelRect`. A more suitable name would be `textRect`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use:

```
let sizeToFit = CGSize(width: messageLabel.frame.size.width,
                       height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
let textSize = messageLabel.sizeThatFits(sizeToFit)
```

Anyway, the way you did it should work as well (you can see on playground both functions return same size):
[image: Playground]

I've added a sample view to the playground, so you can see, the label has black border, and the text fits inside, and is smaller than label. Size is computer properly with both `sizeToFit` and `boundingRect` methods (but `boundingRect` returns not rounded values). I've use this computed size to create a green background view under the text, and it fits it properly.

Comment: In case the `width` would equal `CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude` as height, it would compute size for this text in single line (as it would have enough space to fit the text in single line)

Comment: But the point is that the OP's text already fits in the label, but he/she wants to get the size of the area that the text actually takes up—which is likely smaller than the label's size

Comment: That's the point of setting the width equal to label's width, so it will compute size of text framed exactly like the one in label. Instead, it would compute size of the text, but layed out differently.

Comment: @Dopapp I've replaced the playground screenshot with new one, so you can see it's working

Comment: And here you can see it will also fit the text if it's not full width: http://i.imgur.com/K7R13ID.png and http://i.imgur.com/g8Q07Hg.png

Comment: @IHaveAQuestion, you could show a little more of your code so we could help you. I wonder how this cut off the text while it doesn't change the label size. Or even provide some screenshots of the effect you're re getting.

Comment: Good. Glad to help you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to Try this

```
    let messageLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: _screenSize.width - 30, height: 5))
    messageLabel.font = self.txtDescription.font
    messageLabel.numberOfLines = 0
    messageLabel.text = "Your Massage"
    messageLabel.numberOfLines = 0
    messageLabel.sizeToFit()
    print(messageLabel.frame.size.height)
```

Remove all code Just try this Hope it will wirk

Comment: The text already fits in the label. I want the size of the actual text though, which **is not** equal to the size of the label.

Comment: tell me what functionality you need to implement?

Comment: I have a view that functions as a background view for the UILabel which I want to resize to fit the text as closely as possible—not the label.